# How to pass web service client that were instantiated via fixtures to helper files?

Tags: playwright

I have instantiated a bunch of web service clients that my test cases need via a fixture:

```
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
import { 
  WebServiceOneClient,
  WebServiceTwoClient,
  WebServiceThreeClient
} from 'data/clients';

type OfferHubFixtures = {
  clients: {
    webServiceOneClient: WebServiceOneClient;
    webServiceTwoClient: WebServiceTwoClient;
    webServiceThreeClient: WebServiceThreeClient;
  };
};

export const test = base.extend<MyFixtures>({
    clients: async ({}, use) => {
    const clients = {
      webServiceOneClient: new WebServiceOneClient(`http://webservice-one.com`),
      webServiceTwoClient: new WebServiceTwoClient(
        `https://webservice-two.com`
      ),
      webServiceThreeClient: new WebServiceThreeClient(
        `https://webservice-three.com`,
        {
          pfxFilePath: `../data/certificates/my-cert.pfx`,
          certPassPhrase: process.env.CERT_PASSPHRASE,
        },
      ),
    };
    await use(clients);
  },
});

export { expect, type Page } from '@playwright/test';
```

I know Playwright has it's own http request library but we're pretty entrenched in Axios here so I need to stick with it.

Using all the webserivces this way is great for my tests:

```
test('should create and validate an IOV', async ({ page, clients }) => {
    const response = await clients.webServiceOneClient.getData();
```

My question is how can I get these same web services imported into a helper file?  I need to use a bunch of webservice routes to help with some ancillary code.  I'd rather not maintain two instantiation strategies if possible.